# How to get a particular part of string in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have the below string  i need take out the id (68890) similar date (01/14/2005)

```
CString strsample = "This is demo to capture the details of date (01/14/2005) parent id (68890) read (0)"  

CString strsample =   This is demo (Sample,Application) to capture the details of date (01/14/2005) parent id (68890) read (0) Total(%5)
```

How can i achieve this in C++ is there any way to do in regex or any functions available.

Comment: Are the tokens to be removed always enclosed in parenthesis?

Comment: no the parenthesis has to be removed. just needed as id : 68890 like this or 68890  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way using standard library is to use [std::sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        std::tm t{};
        int id, read;
        auto c = std::sscanf(s.c_str(), 
            "This is demo to capture the details of date (%d/%d/%d) parent id (%d) read (%d)",
            &t.tm_mon,
            &t.tm_mday,
            &t.tm_year,
            &id,
            &read);

        --t.tm_mon;
        t.tm_year -= 1900;

        std::mktime(&t);
        if (c == 5) {
            std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%F") 
                << " id: " << id 
                << " read: " << read
                << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Invalid input\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4P5GY4afz

Comment: I've provided fully working example, I can't help you to fix something what I can't see. I'm guessing you forgot to add `#include <ctime>`.

Comment: Marek Thanks i solved the issue. But when i add a string and put %s to capture it . It fails  i will update my question kindly check

Comment: CString strsample =   This is demo (Sample,Application) to capture the details of date (01/14/2005) parent id (68890) read (0) Total(%5)

Comment: can you please check the question again

Comment: This edit doesn't provide information why you need more help. I have no clue what is your problem now.

Comment: thanks for the reply i have solved the issue :)

Comment: Can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700340/why-sscanf-is-not-handling-or-ignoring-spaces-in-c