# Why sscanf is not handling or ignoring spaces in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, scanf

I have the following line to be put up in `sscanf` but its not accepting white spaces

```
char store_string[25],store_string1[10];
std::tm t={};
int store_integer,store_integer1,store_integer2;
int total_read;
           
char* buff1 = "Demo to dispay (Appname,App usage) with date (03/11/2005) with test id (87773) data added (0) total ((null))";
char* buff2 = "Demo to dispay %s with date (%d/%d/%d) with test id (%d) data added (%d) total ((%d))";
            
total_read = sscanf(buff1, buff2 , store_string,  &t.tm_mon,
&t.tm_mday,
&t.tm_year,
&store_integer,&store_integer1,&store_integer2);
```

Output :

if `buff1` has display `(Appname,Appusage)` it works fine

But If `buff1` has display `(Appname,App usage)` it fails

Comment: What's wrong with `std::istringstream` and `std::getline()`, or other text extraction methods?

Comment: If you are having issues with `sscanf`, why are you using such a complex example?  Why not a simple string that has no space, and one with a space?  Why do you need to introduce `int` variables, dates, etc. to the issue?

Comment: I need to achieve the output with sscanf . I need to know about how we can achieve this in single line instead of creating while loop or forloop. Simple limitations of sscanf .

Comment: I know you want to use `sscanf`.  If you want to learn how to use something correctly, then use a smaller example where you are trying to get the input from just a single string or two strings separated by a space.   It focuses the problem down to only that issue.  All of that extra junk with dates, ints, they serve no purpose in the actual question, except to clutter the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why sscanf is not handling or ignoring spaces in c++?

How else should `sscanf` seperate words/tokens?
From its documentation:

> ["%s"] matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters (a string)

I don't think you can handle this with `sscanf` or in a one-liner at all.
You could do this with [std::string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and [std::string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

### Edit:

[std::regex_match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) might be the most flexible and readable way if you're used to regular expressions.